# Voyager Addition field options

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I'm using Voyager Laravel to build my app, but I'm having some issues regarding the form fields, in my Bread column of "transmission" I have included in the JSON form this:

```
column transmission:

{
    "options": {
        "option1": "Automática",
        "option2": "Manual"
    }
}
```

In the admin is displaying well the information, the problem is when I call it in the frontend for example:

$car->transmission -> outputs -> "option1"

I'm trying to find in the documentation regarding calling only the text/label of the option1 that is correct, but no information I'm finding.

Anybody the uses Voyager had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. That's up to you.
But you can use the key (option1, option2, ...) and rename it to something you can use in your frontend.